# issue in Validation rule firing

Tags: apex, trigger, validation-rule

I have a one validation rule which is checking if phone length is 10 and start not with 03 then thrown an error

I have also written a code in before trigger which is updating 0 to +91 
I have a issue that now my validation is not firing and throwing error if my number start with 03

Pleas help

Comment: You'll need to fix your validation rule.

Comment: the thing is that my before trigger is running which is updating the phone and hence validation is running which is not throwing an error.

Comment: @sam can you paste your validation rule here?